# Docker failed to build: ADD failed:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following volume for the app.

Docker compose file

```
registry-server:
    build:
      context: ./registry-server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /jars
      - /app/
      - ./../registry-server/target:/jars
```

docker file

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre
MAINTAINER IG <ig@ig.com>

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get -y install netcat

ADD /jars/registry-server.jar /app/registry-server.jar

RUN chmod +x /app/registry-server.jar
```

I get error

> ERROR: Service 'registry-server' failed to build: ADD failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder823709495/jars/.jar: no such file or
>   directory

Answer (score 0):

Volumes are not available at build time. They are able at runtime. Your code seems to assume this.

Comment: if i put path to my jar directory direclty in docker file... i get out of context error. Any suggestions how to solve this ?

Comment: is the jar located out of the build directory? you have to change build context so that it would be possible to address the file from that path "downwards"  in the drectory tree